# can't seem to get rid of applications even after formating/restocking/flashing. help?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, factory-reset, partitions, formatting

I have a galaxy tab p1000
I have been trying to upgrade it for 3 days straight now with many tutorials from 2.2 froyo to anything newer but i keep coming back to square one - my old applications keep appearing after flashing/wiping.

It looks like there is some protection on the partitions that doesn't allow me to change/delete data on them.

I tried:
restocking using Odin (with the pit and original firmware)
recovery mode factory reset + cache + dalvik reset
settings -> privacy -> factory reset
removing the applications one by one.

Usually it shows me that they are removed but after restart everything returns.
Many of the apps (3rd party and google) keep crashing all the time.

Nothing helps. each time i bring up the OS again the old apps appear again.
Same happens after connecting to comp and manually deleting stuff - after unmount, they return (everything i deleted).

help ?

Comment: Do the applications return even if you don't associate the tab with your Google account? There's a setting called something like `Automatic restore` in `Settings -> Backup & reset`, you could try disabling this to prevent your previously installed apps from being reinstalled after flashing.

Comment: I can't diassociate my phone from the account - wipes don't do it and when i manually try it from settings then gapps (google framework) crashes and is not removed :(

Comment: Is your bootloader locked or something?  If the flash and factory reset actually succeeded then there would be no way for the apps to come back.

Comment: Bootloader is not locked. The flashing changes OS but apps keep staying there. Someone told me it might be related to internal sd memory going bad.

Comment: after performing the standard restocking procedure (repartitioning with pit and GB safe v5) everything should be ok, but instead, when i enter recovery i get the following error: --Updating application...
E:Can't open directory '/preload/app/'. (No such file or directory)
copy application failed.

Comment: i have been told my internal memory is bad and that it is a typical symptom for p1000 tabs. the only way to recover is to extract the internal mem chip and reformat everything on the sd card :(

Answer (score 1):

If you use recovery to wipe user data, and then wipe your dalvik cache in the advanced settings, then reboot all apps and data will be removed.

Ensure you haven't enabled google restore - when the startup wizard starts, it should ask if you want to restore to this device. Unstick this option.

Comment: No restore nor backup are marked.
Also after wiping all (+dalvik) and booting it will show me the wizard but always remembers previous account and uses it - it wont let me set it on startup. Can't this be a partition mount in Read Only or something like that ?

I wish there was a method to really format all user data maybe with odin ?

Comment: Maybe i can try to return to stock rom froyo 2.2 ? do you know of a tar out there with this original version ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in the end... It was a faulty internal flash memory module.
After researching the web I found that the p1000 has a common internal memory fault that happens after several years.

I can only say that i also found a tutorial that teaches how to remove (physically) the internal memory chip from the motherboard and changing the rom to know how to leave only on the external sd card.

I tried this technique in many variations but i never manage to make it work. Still stuck with the tablet